# Moving view up to accommodate keyboard

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a view with multiple text fields and I want to do the same effect that the Contacts application does when you click on a text field would otherwise be hidden by the keyboard when it comes up. When I dismiss the keyboard I plan on moving the view back down properly.

I suspect that I do this by changing the Frame value, but I need this to be animated so that it isn't jarring to the user.

Advice? Examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping your view in a UIScrollView is indeed the way to go. As well as on the `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate, you could instead subscribe to the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and when you receive a notification that the keyboard did hide/show then scroll your view appropriately. I can post code examples for the keyboard notifications if you need it : )

**Edit**
Figured I'd post the code anyway - someone might find it helpful:

You need to declare listeners for the notifications:

```
NSObject hideObj = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.DidHideNotification, HandleKeyboardDidHide);
NSObject showObj = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.DidShowNotification, HandleKeyboardDidShow);
```

then your Action methods would look something like:

```
void HandleKeyboardDidShow(NSNotification notification)
{
     scrollView.ScrollRectToVisible(textfield.Frame, true);
}

void HandleKeyboardDidHide(NSNotification notification)
{
     // scroll back to normal
}
```

**Edit 2**

So if you'd like to remove the Observers when the view is destroyed, first you need to ensure you assign `NSObject`s when adding the observers then use the following code to remove them:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(showObj);
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(hideObj);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree with the observers, it would be better removing them though when no longer needed. Also, the UIScrollView.ScrollRectToVisible method takes two parameters, not one. The second parameter is for animation.

Comment: Sorry about that! I did it from my phone while on the bus - will correct it tomo morning!

Comment: This was excellent, I really really appreciated it and I hadn't even known about wiring into the UIKeyboard events. The textFieldDidBeginEditing fires every time, which is also awesome.

Comment: I followed this step by step, but it doesn't work.  I put the UIScrollView down, directly on top and in the regular view.  Then I put a few text views.  When the user clicks one of the text views the keyboard immediately covers it up.

Comment: Did you change the `UIScrollView contentSize` to be larger than the screen (to accommodate for scrolling) and then use `scrollToRect` when the text fields become active?

Answer (score 2):

I just did this on an application. I used a scrollview to wrap my entire view, and then used scrollToRectVisible on the textFieldDidEndEditing-delegate method. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The Apple documentation on about the [keyboard management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) topic is pretty good and contains code (at the bottom) for most situations that that you can copy/paste right into your app.

Best of luck.